# Should you aggregate your data

Tags: regression

My theory is that total spending on certain types of services influence wages. My data shows how much we spend on a customer for a service every time we spending money on it (someone might get 50 units of service at different times, we would pay an invoice for each). I think the correct way to handle this is just to aggregate the total spending and predict with that, rather than use the specific payments to predict, but I realized I have never seen this addressed before. Maybe too basic an issue to see on regression.

Comment: Which option is the one relevant to your theory?  That would be the one to go with.

Comment: hi. if it helps, it does help ^^

Comment: There really is no theory unfortunately to build on. I don't work in an area (vocational rehabilitation) with a strong statistical bent. I am testing my own theory that certain types of spending make a difference. And to me it makes sense that the total spending not specific payments matter.  I just wondered if there was some statistical (non-theoretical) reason it would impact the model negatively to use aggregate numbers (essentially one row per individual) rather than one row for each payment for the individual.